# xplico change xi language

Tags: linux, cakephp

I compiled and installed [Xplico](https://www.xplico.org/) on my system! I see that there are many languages inside the source folder at `xplico\system\xi3\app\Locale` .

But I cannot find any option in the UI to change the language! How I can change the Xplico language?

Comment: What does this have to do with CakePHP?

Comment: This app is totally written with CakePHP! and something similar exists in CakePHP projects.  see https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably get better help if you contact their support channels, this is more of a problem with how they implemented things, rather than a general CakePHP problem!

That being said, having a quick look at the source, it seems that they've implemented a language choice in the login action/form:

```php
function login($lan = NULL) {
    if ($lan != NULL) {
        $this->Session->write('Config.language', $lan);
    }

    // ...
}
```

**https://github.com/xplico/xplico/blob/v.1.2.2/system/xi3/app/Controller/UsersController.php#L214-L217**

```php
<script type='text/javascript'>
function Lang()
{
    if ($(this).val() != "--Language--") {
         window.location.href='/users/login/'+$(this).val();
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#lang").change(Lang);
    // ...
});
</script>

<?php if ( $isXplicoRunning == 1) : ?>
  <div id="login" align="center">
  <select id="lang">
    <option>--Language--</option>
    <option value="ara">Arabic</option>
    <!-- ... -->
  </select>
  <h1><?php echo __('Please login'); ?></h1>
  <br />
  <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => 'login')); ?>
  <!-- ... -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

**https://github.com/xplico/xplico/blob/v.1.2.2/system/xi3/app/View/Users/login.ctp**

Comment: Yes! In login form before username there is an option for selecting language! How I didn't see it?! Thank you!